# Floating widgets/pop up window in android

Tags: android, popupwindow

Im developing an app where a floating component should appear when the call is received and the component will have several buttons to perform necessary actions.
I have tried the follow.
I implemented a popup window by making the main activity translucent.when this component pops up, Im able to move it on the screen, but since the activity is translucent, im not able to perform any [image]other activity.

here u can see the popup window, i can move it, but i cannot scroll the menudrawer in the background. How can i implement in such a way that i can perform both operations, i.e on popupwindow and the background screen.

My codes

```
`public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int mCurrentX;
    int mCurrentY;
     private float mDx;
     private float mDy;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         final View cv = new View(this);


            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setBackgroundColor(0xffeeeeee);
            tv.setTextColor(0xff000000);
            tv.setTextSize(24);
            tv.setText("click me\nthen drag me");
            tv.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
          final PopupWindow  mPopup = new PopupWindow(tv, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            OnTouchListener otl = new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int action = event.getAction();

                    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        mDx = mCurrentX - event.getRawX();
                        mDy = mCurrentY - event.getRawY();
                    } else
                    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                        mCurrentX = (int) (event.getRawX() + mDx);
                        mCurrentY = (int) (event.getRawY() + mDy);
                        mPopup.update(mCurrentX, mCurrentY, -1, -1);

                    }
                    return true;
                }
            };
            tv.setOnTouchListener(otl);

            mCurrentX = 20;
            mCurrentY = 50;

            cv.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mPopup.showAtLocation(cv, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, mCurrentX, mCurrentY);
                }
            });
    }

}`
```

manifest

```
`<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

               <activity
                android:name="PopupMainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.FloatingWindow.Popup"
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"
                android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
                android:exported="true"
                tools:ignore="ExportedActivity" />

    </application>`
```

please help me on this. I want to implement a widget kind of component on the whole. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start a foreground Service and draw using the WindowManager on top of everything else, manage your popup position, size, etc...

```
WindowManger windowManager = Context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
```

You will also have to add this permission "android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" to your manifest.

A simpler solution would be to use a library called [StandOut](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut), it basically takes care of all that I mentioned above and provide extra features like:

- Window decorators (titlebar, minimize/close buttons, border, resize handle)
- Windows are moveable and resizable. You can bring-to-front, minimize,
  and close
- Minimized windows can be restored (the example APK demos this using
  the notification panel)
- Create multiple types of windows, and multiple windows of each type

Comment: Thanks for the answer, some more detail on how to use the library please? Im new to android and learning some concepts to i may require more help! Thanks!

Comment: Check the library example project, specially StandOutExampleActivity.java, SimpleWindow.java and AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @MostafaGazar when StandOut library is showing CommingSoon?